# How to translate CryptoJS AES into java code

Tags: encryption, cryptojs

I want to translate CryptoJS code into java code .This is the javascript code:

```
CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('hello',CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.MD5("http://stackoverflow.com")), {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("1234567812345678")})
```

Above the code result invoke to string is 'QtzDsbCgmA9+XBVEsEm70w=='

Then I get the key value by CryptoJS.MD5("http://stackoverflow.com").toString() method(key =  57f4dad48e7a4f7cd171c654226feb5a)

This is the java code:

```
 try {
        String content = "hello";
        String key = "57f4dad48e7a4f7cd171c654226feb5a";
        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(key.getBytes("utf-8")));
        SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
        byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();


        SecretKeySpec key1 = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("utf-8");


        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key1,new IvParameterSpec("1234567812345678".getBytes("UTF-8")));

        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(byteContent);
        System.out.println(new String(result).equals("QtzDsbCgmA9+XBVEsEm70w=="));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but the output result is false.How to fix the java code to change the result to true.

Comment: Well... You aren't base64 encoding the bytes before comparing them?

Comment: Well... `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.MD5("http://stackoverflow.com"))` is a type mismatch. Anything could happen. You either want `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(CryptoJS.MD5("http://stackoverflow.com").toString())` or simply `CryptoJS.MD5("http://stackoverflow.com")`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

According to @Luka Park advice,I have solve to my question.This is my solution:

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] raw = sKey.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivParameter.getBytes());
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(sSrc.getBytes("utf-8"));
    return new BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypted);
```